# Zooming and Panning svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to create an interactive map of floors of the building.
And i use svg map.

I am try to zoom it like this example: http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/
In this example svg map imported in tags `<img src="some.svg">`, and work fine.
But, i want to refer to elements by id on this svg, and for that i must import svg file as `<object data="some.svg"></object>`.

But after that zoom not working ((
I know about Raphael and svgpan, but it's very hard for understanding, and i think they a very big for this small task.

Comment: Can you post the code you have at the moment?

Comment: Nat, if you do not complicate, please look code in my repository in github: https://github.com/Nmishin/map/tree/master/tests
please see file kartograph1.html.
thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can use pure svg instead <svg>...</svg>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank everyone for help!
Francis, thank you for [Ariutta svgPanZoom](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) plugin, it works great for me!
I am load my svg map with `<embed>` tag, and i can use svg dom like this:

`$(window).load(function(){
    var svg = document.getElementById("chart").getSVGDocument();
});`

Answer (score 7):

If you want access to your svg elements, then the best way would be to load your svg file `inline` using `xmlHTTPRequest` to place the response text into a DIV's `innerHTML`. See example below.

As for zoom/pan, I have recently tested 
[Ariutta svgPanZoom](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) and find it has a nice mousewheel zoom. It is compact.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Load SVG file file Inline</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='padding:0px;font-family:arial'>
<center><h4>Load SVG file Inline</h4>
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
Load an svg file as inline SVG. This provides dynamic svg applications seamless DOM access to its elements. Uses <b>XMLHttpRequest</b>. It can be loaded as a DIV's <b>innerHTML</b> via a string dump (<b>responseText</b>).
</div>
<div id="svgDiv"></div>
<p><button onClick=changeSomeValues()>change</button></p>
SVG DOM:<br />
<textarea id=mySvgValue style='width:90%;height:200px;font-size:120%;font-family:lucida console;'></textarea>
  <br />Javascript:<br />
<textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
</center>
<div id='browserDiv' style='padding:3px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;background-color:gainsboro;'></div>

<script id=myScript>
function loadSVGasXML()
{
    var SVGFile="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4a/Commons-logo.svg"
    var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest;
    function handler(){
        if(loadXML.readyState == 4 &&loadXML.status == 200){
               svgDiv.innerHTML=loadXML.responseText
               mySvgValue.value= svgDiv.innerHTML
        }
    }
    if (loadXML != null){
        loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
        loadXML.onreadystatechange = handler;
        loadXML.send();
    }
}
//--button---
function changeSomeValues()
{
    path4653.style.fill="green"
    mySvgValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}
</script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{
    loadSVGasXML()
    jsValue.value=myScript.text
    mySvgValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```